# memory reallocation in c

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new very interested in c programming now i am writing a c program which for dynamically memory allocation.

These are the the stages of the program:

1. it gets `n` numbers from user
2. it prints them
3. it gets another `n` numbers from the user
4. it prints both sets of numbers

my program works fine for small values of `n`, but not for large ones, such as 200000 numbers. i.e first I entered 100000 numbers then I entered another 100000 numbers.

It executes fine for the first set but then it gives a segmentation fault. I use `gdb` for debugging. It shows SIGSEGV error.

Can anybody explain what happened and give me a solution for it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main(void)
{

    unsigned int *p=NULL;
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int *a;
    unsigned int *t;
    unsigned int k=0;

    printf("Enter no.of elements...");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    p = (unsigned int*)malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned int));
    a = p;
    t = p;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++, *p++, k++) {
        scanf("%d",p);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++,a++) {
        printf("Element No-%d %d Address->%d\n", i, *a, a);
    }

    a=t;

    printf("next time...how many elements do you enter");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    t=p;
    a = (unsigned int*)realloc((void *)a, n*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++, *t++ ,k++) {
        scanf("%d",t);
    }

    printf("next time...printing..\n");

    for (i=0; i<k; i++, a++) {
        printf("Element No-%d %d Address->%d\n",i,*a,a);
    }

    free(p);
    free(a);


}
```

Comment: I was with you right up until the "give me a solution." that triggered my auto-close-reflex.

Comment: I took the liberty of making your question and code more legible.  Please check that I didn't mess it up.

Comment: LOL WhozCraig. You'd think these homework answer hunters would at least disguise their questions a bit better!

Comment: The title is wrong, it is not *program* reallocation, but just *memory* reallocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realloc` changes the size of the allocation, it doesn't grow the allocation by the size you specify.

So you need to do

```
a=realloc(a, original_size + extent_size);
```

([You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc` in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

Another note:

```
t=p;
...
a=t;
...
t=p;
a=realloc(...);
```

You can't use `t` after the realloc, since realloc could have changed the block's address. Put `t=a;` after the realloc. (And use more descriptive names, your code is very hard to follow.)

Comment: Thanks for responding my program and you said that realloc changes the size of allocation so how can i get back the numbers which are allocated at the previous location and how can add another numbers after at the end of previous memory location ?

Comment: There's no standard/portable way to know, you need to keep track of that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`, not `<malloc.h>` which is deprecated. Please also indent correctly your code

The two lines:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++,*p++,k++)
   scanf("%d",p);
```

seem suspicious. Why the `*p`? I would make it

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++, p++)
  if (scanf(" %d", p)<1) 
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debugging info during compilation (with `gcc` that means `gcc -Wall -g`) and to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and the memory leak detector (e.g. `valgrind`) to debug your program.

You might want to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, and you definitely should test the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` (all could fail by returning `NULL`).

And as Mat answered, your `realloc` call was incorrect.